# How to to match exact number in regex?

Tags: regex

I have this regex `/^\+[0-9]{12}$/`, but I want to measure it so that:
I must start input with +380, like this:
**+380**501112233

Also need to have a reex for matching **+** on start and **12** or less digits
How to do that? Thanks is adnvance

Comment: People active on this site tend to not do your work for you. Instead, they will try to help you if you present a specific problem you have run into while _you_ were doing your work ... [https://www.regular-expressions.info/](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is an excellent site to learn about the essentials of regexen including what you need to know to answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the regex that you would be looking for,

`^\+380[0-9]{9}$`

This regex ensures that you start with `+380`.
It also ensures that there are 12 digits, inclusive of `380`, after `+`.

Find the explanation here, https://regex101.com/r/UDjaZV/2/